# Rest API - Why is Postman sending me back empty curly brackets with GET

Tags: rest, api, symfony, postman

I'm working on a REST API. Hence I created my entities like for example this one musee.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Musee
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="musee")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MuseeRepository")
 */
class Musee
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private$adresse;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $horaireOuverture;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $horaireFermeture;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Bateau", mappedBy="musee")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bateaux;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * @param string $nom
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * @param string $adresse
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getHoraireOuverture()
{
    return $this->horaireOuverture;
}

/**
 * @param int $horaireOuverture
 */
public function setHoraireOuverture($horaireOuverture)
{
    $this->horaireOuverture = $horaireOuverture;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getHoraireFermeture()
{
    return $this->horaireFermeture;
}

/**
 * @param int $horaireFermeture
 */
public function setHoraireFermeture($horaireFermeture)
{
    $this->horaireFermeture = $horaireFermeture;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getBateaux()
{
    return $this->bateaux;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $bateaux
 */
public function setBateaux($bateaux)
{
    $this->bateaux = $bateaux;
}


}
```

My MuseeRepository also exists and in my config.yml I put (both were installed with composer) :

```
# Nelmio CORS
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/api':

# FosRest
fos_rest:
routing_loader:
    include_format: false
view:
    view_response_listener: true
format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

In my MuseeController here is what I put:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Fanny
 * Date: 28/03/2018
 * Time: 16:13
*/

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use AppBundle\Entity\Musee;

class MuseeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"musee"})
     * @Rest\Get("/musee")
    */

   // Fonction qui renvoie toutes all musee
    public function findMusee()
   {
        $musee = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Musee')
        ->findAll();

    return $musee;
}


}
```

I also used a serializer file, I wonder if my problem does not come from there... Though all this elements are in my database as I generated it with doctrine.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Musee:
  attributes:
    id:
      groups: ['musee']
    nom:
      groups: ['musee']
    adresse:
      groups: ['musee']
    horaire_ouverture:
      groups: ['musee']
    horaire_fermeture:
      groups: ['musee']
    bateaux:
      groups: ['musee']
```

My problem is when I try to call my localhost:8000/musee, I get the good amount of brackets compared to what is inside my database, but they appear empty.

I think I might be missing a step but I'm not sure where to search. Where do you think I should look?

**UPDATE:**

The version of Symfony that I have is 3.4.
I enabled serializer in my config.yml and installed with composer : jms/serializer-bundle.
In my app Kernel I have :

```
 new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
 new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
 new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
```

The problem is common to all my entities. I get the right amount of brackets but no content inside.

Comment: postman is probably returning empty curly brackets as no data matches what you asked for

Comment: Might be a problem with normalization of your entity.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I generated my database with doctrine and I have filled my database. Could it be that the problem comes from my serializer perhaps?

Comment: @paolo I'm not sure of what you mean by normalization ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how it works, but you need to tell the normalizer which attributes of your model shall be included in the response. Apparently, the normalizer configuration is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see, I updated my comment, I have a serializer file but I'm not sure of what I'm getting wrong. Is it maybe that I am missing something to link it? I did enable it to true in my config.yml

Comment: That's because your model does not implement any kind of serialization. There are some bundles that provide that functionality, but you can simply implement http://php.net/manual/es/class.jsonserializable.php interface and return an array with the properties you want in the ::jsonSerialize(): array method.

Answer (score 0):

`FOSRestBundle`'s docs cover the serialization here: **[Enable a Serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html#c-enable-a-serializer)**

But CSS seems to be falling apart presently, so I'll quote it:

> C) Enable a Serializer
>
> This bundle needs a serializer to work correctly. In most cases, you'll need to enable a serializer or install one. This bundle tries the following (in the given order) to determine the serializer to use:
>
> 1. The one you configured using `fos_rest.services.serializer` (if you did).
> 2. The JMS serializer, if the `JMSSerializerBundle` is **available** (and registered).
> 3. The `Symfony Serializer` if it's **enabled** (or any service called serializer).

## Questions:

1. Which version of `Symfony` do you use?
2. Have you enabled `Serializer` component?
3. Is the issue limited to `Musee` or all entities?

Please update the question with these and we can follow up.

## Update:

Can't help but wonder if it has anything to do with all services becoming private in `Symfony 3.4`. Maybe `FOSRestBundle` cannot find the `JMSSerializerBundle`. Which version of `FOSRestBundle` you have installed?

I see that all released versions of `FOSRestBundle` specify the `^3.0` dependency requirement, but the above is specific to `v3.4`.

Comment: Oh I see, it seems that the version of FOSRest that I have is ^2.3. Perhaps I should try to change my Symfony version?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry at first I thought you meant the ^3.0 of Symfony! I don't know a lot about Symfony yet, so I'm not sure if it was the best way to change the FOSRest version but I changed it in my composer.json and did a composer update. But I got this error "The requested package friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^3.0 exists as friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[0.10.0, 0.11.0, .... dev-master, 2.3.x-dev, dev-silverbackdan-master, dev-xabbuh-service
-container] but these are rejected by your constraint. " I'm not sure to understand which constraint they are talking about, maybe I didn't do it right?

Comment: I'm not sure how but the issuer is fixed. I recreated a project and I'm getting the info I want. I will keep on with this one. Thank you for pondering the issue with me! It's too bad I can't find what was causing the problem. I probably did something somewhere that wasn't ok but right now I cannot see it. Anyway, thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are returning an array of entities instead of valid json response. I am working in REST/API too, but without FOSRest, so I cant be completely sure how serialization happens with FOSREST, but definitively is that.
A workaround could be returning a JSONResponse in your controller, with all of your entities serialized somehow instead of returning the array of entities as you are currently doing here

```
return $musee;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems that when I recreated the project the error didn't reproducted itself... I cannot really explain the issue for now but I'll put it there if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated my project and this time didn't get an error... I'm not sure of what was the reason but I used the same Symfony versions and commands. So there was probably a problem somewhere even if I try to compare both and din't see any difference. I'll try to tell you if I find it.